# Issue a Conditional Redirect in Drupal 7

Tags: 7, hooks, nodes

I have a custom payment form that redirects to a 'Thank You' page on success. The page is just a Page type node, so someone can control the content of the page.

What I wanted to do was add a little extra, and prevent the page from being seen unless they had just come from the form.

I tried using 3 functions. hook_node_view, hook_node_view_alter, and hook_init.

I thought the first two would allow me to check the node path or nid, and redirect if I needed to, but they did not seem to be called. Additionally, I tried

```
mymodule_init() {
  global $user;
  krumo($user);exit;
}
```

That was not being hit, either. The rest of the module works fine, custom menu item, custom form, validate/submit/mail hooks. I am stumped.

How can I check a node value when loading, take action, and furthermore, why is hook_init() not dumping/exiting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use `hook_init`, but `hook_boot` as you want to perform the check when caching is turned on. That would also be the best explanation as to why your `exit` doesn't work. That or you forgot to clear cache after implementing the hook. (All hooks are cached in D7)

Comment: Hmm.. Had to clear the cache 3 times before it picked up changes.